# How to convert page content in multiple page PDF file?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation, jspdf

The HTML/JS code generates 16 tables of 7x7 size. I'm trying to convert to multiple page PDF file the content of whole page visible page. I'm using printPDF function (cdnjs, jspdf) code borrowed from a question here in SO, but not sure why is only printing the first page. This is the code I have so far and can be tested [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cqpgjer8/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Table Generator</title>
  <style>
      body {
        text-align: center;
        background-color:DarkGray;
        display:table;      
      }
      

      #inputContainer {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      #tableContainerZ {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 -25px;
        padding: 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        
        width: 1000px; 
        background-color: powderblue;       
      }
      
      #tableContainer {   
        display: flex;
        background-color: powderblue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 800px;
        height: 1000px;
        margin-left: -400px;
        /* -1/2 width */
        margin-top: -150px;
        /* -1/2 height */     
      }
      
     
      .tableWrapperLeft {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 25px;
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        display: flex;      
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-end;
        
      }

      .tableWrapperRight {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 25px;
       border: 2px solid yellow;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;        
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        width: 288px;
        height: 288px;
      }

      td {
        border: 1px dotted black;
        text-align: center;
      }

      td:first-child {
        border-left: 1px dotted black;
      }

      tr:first-child td {
        border-top: 1px dotted black;
      }

      .tableWrapperRight table {
        border: 4px solid black;
      }

      .tableWrapperLeft table {
        border: 4px solid black;
      }

      td:nth-child(2n):not(:last-child) {
        border-right-width: 4px;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-right-color: black;
      }
      
  
      
  </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="inputContainer">
    
    <button onClick="printToPDF();">
        Print to PDF
    </button>

  </div>

  <div id="tableContainer"></div>

  <script>
  
    window.onload = function() {
        generateTables();
    };
    

    function generateRandomArray(size) {
      var array = [];
      for (var row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        var rowData = [];
        for (var col = 0; col < size; col++) {
          rowData.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        }
        array.push(rowData);
      }
      return array;
    }


    function generateTable(array) {
      var table = document.createElement('table');

      for (var row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');

        for (var col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
          var tableData = document.createElement('td');
          tableData.textContent = array[row][col];
          tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
        }

        table.appendChild(tableRow);
      }

      return table;
    }

    function generateTables() {
      var tableCount = 16;
      var tableSize = 7;
      var tablesPerColumn = Math.ceil(tableCount / 2);

      var tableContainer = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
      tableContainer.innerHTML = '';

      var leftColumn = document.createElement('div');
      leftColumn.className = 'tableWrapperLeft';
      var rightColumn = document.createElement('div');
      rightColumn.className = 'tableWrapperRight';

      for (var i = 0; i < tableCount; i++) {
        var tableArray = generateRandomArray(tableSize);
        var table = generateTable(tableArray);

        if (i < tablesPerColumn) {
          leftColumn.appendChild(table);
        } else {
          rightColumn.appendChild(table);
        }
      }

      tableContainer.appendChild(leftColumn);
      tableContainer.appendChild(rightColumn);
    }
    
    
    function printToPDF() {
    console.log('converting...');
    
    var printableArea = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
    
    html2canvas(printableArea, {
        useCORS: true,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
    
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    
        var pageHeight = 1000;
        var pageWidth = 900;
        for (var i = 0; i <= printableArea.clientHeight / pageHeight; i++) {
            var srcImg = canvas;
            var sX = 0;
            var sY = pageHeight * i; // start 1 pageHeight down for every new page
            var sWidth = pageWidth;
            var sHeight = pageHeight;
            var dX = 0;
            var dY = 0;
            var dWidth = pageWidth;
            var dHeight = pageHeight;
    
            window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', pageWidth);
            onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', pageHeight);
            var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(srcImg, sX, sY, sWidth, sHeight, dX, dY, dWidth, dHeight);
    
            var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
            var width = onePageCanvas.width;
            var height = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;
    
            if (i > 0) // if we're on anything other than the first page, add another page
            pdf.addPage(612, 791); // 8.5" x 11" in pts (inches*72)
    
            pdf.setPage(i + 1); // now we declare that we're working on that page
            pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'PNG', 20, 40, (width * .62), (height * .62)); // add content to the page
    
        }
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
        }
    });
    }   
    
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```